# SQL Add One Day To Query Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to add one day to query date, then get all the data greater than today.

Fields:
valid_to

Table:
Post

```
Select * from posts where valid_to + 1 > Now()
```

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. I have removed the conflicting tags.

Comment: Please be clear: You want all data valid until yesterday or all data valid until today or all data valid until yesterday at the same time as now (e.g. now it's 12:42, so get all data valid until yesterday 12:42)?

Comment: You would typically have the operation on the right hand side, so your column remains unaltered and the DBMS sees that it can use an index on that column, if such exists. Something along the lines of `where valid_to > now() - interval '1 day'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Postgres SQL you want here is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE valid_to + interval '1' day > NOW();
```

As for the logic, it is not clear this is the query you need without seeing some sample data.